# Run one command after another, even if I suspend the first one (Ctrl-z)

Tags: bash, shell, command, signals, suspend

I know in bash I can run one command after another by separating them by semicolons, like

```
$ command1; command2
```

Or if I only want `command2` to run only if `command1` succeeds, using `&&`:

```
$ command1 && command2
```

This works, but if I suspend `command1` using `Ctrl-z`, in the first case, it runs `command2` immediately, and in the second case, it doesn't run it at all.  How can I run commands in sequence, but still be able to suspend the first command, but not have the second run until I have restarted it (with `fg`) and it finishes?  I'd prefer something as simple to type as possible, as I would like to do this interactively.  Or maybe I just need to set an option somewhere.

By the way, what is the proper term for what `Ctrl-z` does?

Comment: `command1; command2` should do exactly what you want. As to the terminology, Ctrl-Z *suspends* the process.

Comment: Well it doesn't.  I'm running bash version `4.2.8(2)-release` on Mac OS X 10.8 in iTerm2.

Comment: Thanks for the terminology.  I'll update the question to use it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it doesn't. I think you need a subshell. See my answer.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
(command1; command2)
```

Note the added parentheses.

Comment: Awesome!  Now, do you or anyone care to give an explanation as to why it behaves the way it does for these three cases (`command1; command2`, `command1 && command 2`, and `(command1; command2)`)?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure. Perhaps someone could enlighten both of us.

Comment: Technically, you don't suspend processes with Control-z, you suspend *jobs*. With `command1; command2`, the active job is just the process `command1` when you press Control-z, so it is suspended and the next job (`command2`) begins. With `(command1; command2)`, the active job consists of the subshell that runs the two commands, so the entire subshell is suspended by Control-z. You can confirm this by running the `jobs` command after suspending each.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, and what about the `command1 && command2` option?  That is what I frequently encounter.  Even though the _job_ consists of both commands together, I have also noticed that the second command won't execute after backgrounding.  `(command1 && command2)` works, of course, but I often do not know that I want to background a process ahead of time. Otherwise I would have executed it as a background job from the start.

Comment: `command1 && command2` is actually two jobs (a job consists of a pipeline, and the `&&` list consists of two (single-process) pipelines, `command1` and `command2`). The second command doesn't run until `command1` exits (with zero status), and `command1` doesn't exit when it is stopped.

Answer (score 11):

In Bash, when you place a job into the background (using CTRL+Z or &) it does not wait for the job to finish, and gives an exit code of zero (success).  That much you have observed, and it is documented in the `man` pages.

The behaviour of logical "AND", &&, is that it tests from left-to right.  Each part must be successful, so if the first is unsuccessful then the second will not run.  So with && it runs commands from left to right until one of them fails.  The definition of success is an exitcode ($?) of zero.

Contrast this with logical "OR", ||, which runs commands from left to right until one of them *works*.

Explaination of the subshell solution give by @NPE can also be found in the `man` pages:

*Compound commands and command sequences of the form ‘a ; b ; c’ are not
handled gracefully when process suspension is attempted.  When  a  process is stopped, the shell immediately executes the next command in the sequence.  It suffices to place the sequence of commands between parentheses to force it into a subshell, which may be stopped as a unit.*

The proper term for CTRL+Z is the *suspend* character, again from the `man` pages:

*Typing the suspend character (typically ^Z, Control-Z) while a process is running causes that process to be stopped and returns control to bash.*

(Sorry to quote the `man` pages so much, but they really are your friends and worth reading)

If you look at `stty -a` you will see something like this:

```
susp = ^Z;
```

So you can alter it, hence the phrase "typically".  Don't do that though, it will confuse the heck out of everyone.  The terminal driver raises a SIGTSTP signal which is trapped by Bash.

Comment: I still don't understand the behavior with &&. Does suspending the process cause it to return nonzero?

Comment: What man pages are these from?  I figured the answer might be there, but I had no idea where to even start.

Comment: `&&` joins two *pipelines*, and each pipeline is a separate job. (Note that pipeline is one or more commands joined by a `|`, which means `command1` is technically a single one-command pipeline).