# Git hook not running 2 consecutive commands

Tags: git, bash

I'm trying to create a `pre-push` hook to run `php-cs-fixer` before every push.

This is the current `pre-push` hook I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec php-cs-fixer fix . --config-file=".php_cs" && git commit -am 'PSR-2'
```

The first command gets trigger without a problem.
Only the `git commit -am 'PSR-2` doesn't. To be more precise, the `php-cs-fixer` runs followed by this error `error: failed to push some refs to ..`

I also tried the following without luck:

```
#!/bin/sh

php-cs-fixer fix . --config-file=".php_cs" && git commit -am 'PSR-2'
```

-

```
#!/bin/sh

(php-cs-fixer fix . --config-file=".php_cs" && git commit -am 'PSR-2')
```

According to this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600319/bash-run-one-command-after-another-even-if-i-suspend-the-first-one-ctrl-z) question, it should run only if cmd1 has succeeded.

Comment: Did you try `exec (php-cs-fixer fix . --config-file=".php_cs" ; git commit -am 'PSR-2')`?

Comment: Remove `exec`: `exec` replaces the current process by the command given in argument and never returns. It's both wrong and useless here.

Comment: As a side note, your shebang is wrong: it should be `#!/bin/sh` (with no spaces between `#!` and `/bin/sh`).

Comment: Same happens when removing `exec`. I edited the question with the error given after `php-cs-fixer` runs.

Comment: So your first command failed (you have explicit errors—fix them!) and the second command is not executed. So all is as expected, isn't it? By the way, you second version with enclosing parentheses is useless! VonC mislead you with wrong/useless/random/inappropriate informations. Now your problem is about fixing `php-cs-fixer`. Good luck.

Comment: Yes the first command 'failed', in the sence that `php-cs-fixer` fixed some files. This is expected behaviour, nothing wrong with `php-cs-fixer`. That is why there's a `git commit -am` command to commit those changes before pushing.

Comment: The `git commit -am` _will be executed_ ***only if*** _`php-cs-fixer`_ ***succeeds***.

Comment: Oh I see! need to use `;` instead of `&&`. Thank you!, works like a charm now :)

Comment: Or just put the two commands on separate lines.

Answer (score 3):

The `exec` builtin command replaces the shell with the given program. It does **NOT** fork a new process to execute `php-cs-fixer`.

Since the shell is replaced by the `php-cs-fixer` program the `&& git commit ...` is never executed.

Take a look at the [manpage of `exec`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> If command is specified, it replaces the shell. No new process is created.

The first line of `php-cs-fixer` should look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

and the `php-cs-fixer` should have execute permissions `chmod +x php-cs-fixer`.

Than you can just use it

```
php-cs-fixer fix . --config-file=".php_cs" && git commit -am 'PSR-2'
```

Comment: Since OP's shebang is `#!/bin/sh`, maybe the POSIX reference is more appropriate than the Bash reference about `exec`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_20_01

Comment: Hm thanks for you reply. Using `#!/usr/bin/env php

php-cs-fixer fix . --config-file=".php_cs" && git commit -am 'PSR-2'` shows the text (line break in between), but doesn't execute it. php-cs-fixer has executable rights. (I can run it outside the git hook)