# How do I suspend and resume a sequence of commands in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have `cmd2` that needs to follow after `cmd1` completes. I need to pause `cmd1` sometimes.

I type in

```
$ cmd1 && cmd2
```

and then press `Ctrl+Z (Stop)` to stop `cmd1`. Now, `cmd1` is paused but when I resume, it does not start `cmd2` after completion of `cmd1`.

I type in

```
$ cmd1 ; cmd2
```

and then I press `Ctrl+Z (Stop)` to stop `cmd1`. Now `cmd1` is paused but it immediately starts `cmd2`.  However, I wish to start `cmd2` only after `cmd1` finishes.

I did some research and someone suggested an elegant way in `zsh` but I wonder if there is an elegant way of doing it in `bash`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600319/bash-run-one-command-after-another-even-if-i-suspend-the-first-one-ctrl-z

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run it in a subshell:

```
(cmd1 && cmd2)
```

Example:

```
$ (sleep 5 && echo 1)                        # started the command chain
^Z
[1]+  Stopped         ( sleep 5 && echo 1 )  # stopped before `sleep 5` finished
$ fg                                         # resumed
( sleep 5 && echo 1 )
1                                            # `sleep 5` finished and `echo 1` ran
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it is that easy and overthink-ed myself! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @codeforester, I didn't understand that why does it needs a subshell ?

Comment: I think the command buffer gets flushed when we stop and resume.  In case of the subshell, it already has the full command line and it is not reading it from an input device.  That's my guess.

Comment: @codeforester, I don't think so. Because, It is able to resume `cmd1`. Why not `cmd2` ? Even though, we have entered as a single command line.