# How to start one command then start a series of commands in parallel after the first finishes?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to start a command, wait until it finishes, and then start a series of commands following it, and I would like to chain these together.

I have tried testing with variations of commands using the ; and && operators, but my desired behavior has been expressed.

What I'd like is to run the following:

```
command1 && command2 && command3; (command4; command5; command6;)
```

Given the above command, I would want the following to occur:

```
Run command1
When command1 has successfully completed, start command2
When command2 has successfully completed, start command3
When command3 has succuessfully completed start (command4, command5 and command6) in parallel
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: run one command after another, even if I suspend the first one (Ctrl-z)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600319/bash-run-one-command-after-another-even-if-i-suspend-the-first-one-ctrl-z)

Answer (score 1):

This code would achieve what you want:

```
command1 && command2 && command3; nohup command4 & nohup command5 & nohup command6 &
```

Note: using `nohup` on the terminal (not on a script) can hold the prompt and create a file `nohup.out` somewhere if you don't use a redirection such as `> /dev/null 2>&1` when invoking it.

Using `nohup` would guarantee that the processes invoked with `nohup` would continue running even if you close the terminal where you run the command (basically, `nohup` runs the given command with hangup signals ignored, so that the command can continue running in the background after you log out).

This simpler code version could also work:

```
command1 && command2 && command3; command4 & command5 & command6 &
```

However, if you use the simpler version above and you (for example) close the terminal before (say) `command 5` was completed, that command would be interrupted and not finish.

Comment: Did you test this?  I expect you to get a syntax error.  Try `nohup command4 & nohup command5 & nohup command 6` (eg, omit the semi-colons.  `&` replaces the semi-colon, it does not precede it.)

Comment: You're correct, syntax error. I posted before testing from the top of my head and was testing now and getting the error. I fixed the code, now it works as it should.

Comment: Interesting about the `&` not needing a `;` learned something :) I've only run them on their own lines, never would have noticed