# Stop and restart a loop in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, process

After running the following command...

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do sleep 3; echo $i; done
```

...if I wait a few seconds and hit <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then I get the following:

```
1
2
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 3
```

Now if I use `fg` to resume the process, it resumes the `sleep 3` part of the loop, but does not finish the loop:

```
$ fg
sleep 3
$
```

Is there a way to stop the process such that the loop can be continued later?

Comment: Replace `for i in {1..10}; do sleep 3; echo $i; done` with `(for i in {1..10}; do sleep 3; echo $i; done)`. See: [Bash: run one command after another, even if I suspend the first one (Ctrl-z)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13600319/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other mentioned you need to start new sub-shell with `(for i in {1..10}; do sleep 3; echo $i; done)`
You can suspend with ctrl+z. If you run  `jobs` command, you should see the suspended jobs. Then resume it via `fg` or `bg` commands

[image]

Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipathi/chccLdLt/3/